# JPA Enum Inheritance

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have an interface called 'Category' and 4 enum implementing this interface. 
Those enums are decided in categories and have different types in it. 
Example:

```
#Interface
interface BillCategory

#Enum 1
public enum GroceryPurchase implements BillCategory {
  VEGAN,  
  VEGETARIAN,
  PESCITARIAN,
  FLEXITARIAN, 
  OMNIVORE


#Enum 2
enum ElectronicPurchase implements BillCategory{ 
 SMARTPHONE, HARDWARE, SOFTWARE }
```

I aded the field to an entity class.

```
private BillCategory billCategory;
```

And when I start the Spring Environemnt I get the following Hibernate/JPA error:

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: net.wizypay.wizypay.bill.model.BillCategory, at table: bill_entity, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(bill_category)]
```

How can I solve this problem? I do not want to summarise the enums to one. Is there a better approach? Or just impossible to persist such data.

Comment: Say enum ElectronicPurchase has a value 'X', so what goes to the database is likely the value 'X' unless it's an ordinal value you're storing. How would Hibernate upon loading the entity know that it needs to use enum class ElectronicPurchase when all it has is a base type 'BillCategory' and a value 'X' ? It can't. So no, you can't do this. Maybe with a converter it could be done.

Comment: If I am not totally mistaken, it would make more sense, to have `BillCategory` be an `enum` and let it have instances called `GroceryPurchase` and `ElectronicPurchase`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer no because you cannot inherit from an enum
atGimby Okay thanks, maybe someone nows a solution but I guess meanwhile I have to come up with another approach

Comment: Why does the field in the entity class need to be of type `BillCategory`? Entities are meant to represent data, so why can't you use just the enum? i.e. `private GroceryPurchase billCategory;`, add the corresponding getters and setters and then, in your business logic code just safely use `BillCategory` methods. The fact that you are using the `BillCategory` interface as the type of an entity field indicates that you might have some flaw in your design.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Because it can either be the enum GroceryPurchase or ElectronicPurchase or one of the others

Comment: And thats why `BillCategory` should actually be the enum... What enum values do you even store in the enums `GroceryPurchase` and `ElectronicPurchase`?

Comment: Values belonging to this type of Purchase. Maybe I should overthink the categorization and categorization of categorization

Comment: Yeah, you should definitly overthink this. Can you give an value you actually implemented there? I can't think of anything you would put there

Comment: @XtremeBaumer edited above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alrght, not sure how `Smartphone` is NOT `Hardware`, but okay. Here is how I would do it (Not sure if I discard something you actually need now). Make `BillCategory` an enum. Add private fields `PurchaseType` (this could also be another enum containing values like `GroceryPurchase` or `ElectronicPurchase`) and `Category` (this is String and matches the enum name). That should solve your problem with hibernate.

Code illustrating what I mean:

```
enum BillCategory {

    VEGAN("VEGAN", PurchaseType.GroceryPurchase), 
    VEGETARIAN("VEGETARIAN",PurchaseType.GroceryPurchase),
    SMARTPHONE("SMARTPHONE", PurchaseType.ElectronicPurchase);

    private String category;
    private PurchaseType type;

    BillCategory(String category, PurchaseType type) {
        this.category = category;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public PurchaseType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(PurchaseType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

}

enum PurchaseType {
    ElectronicPurchase, GroceryPurchase;
}
```

You should then also annotate `private BillCategory billCategory;` in your entity class with something like `@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)`, or some other `EnumType`, depending on how you want it to be saved in the database

Comment: Smartphones are Hardware though, but it's interesting if the buying behaviour of a random customer ist more in smartphones than regular hardware. But thanks it helped me!

Answer (score 2):

You have two conflicting goals in your mind and try to satisfy both, without realizing it.

When you split constants into many enums implementing the same interface, you are aiming for extensibility: you remove the dependency from the code using enums to the enums themselves. You are free to create new enums without breaking any existing code.

When you are using JPA to map from the relations into Java objects - you aim for centralizing the code that builds and serializes your objects. Note that - unless you are using reflection - this code must depend on all the types you are using, because it needs to be able to build all the values. Specifically, if the database stores a string that says "APPLE", it will need to know if it's Computer.APPLE or Fruit.APPLE.

Unless you use reflection - store the name of the class in question - it's impossible to do it in a general way. And if you use reflection, you loose another thing: abstraction. Suddenly your database data is dependent on your Java implementation.

You must:

- embrace the impossibility of what you are trying to accomplish
- prioritize your requirements

Depending on your requirements, one clean solution would be to build a converter with methods along the line of:

```
  BillCategory fromString(String category);
  String fromCategory(BillCategory category);
```

This will keep both the database clean and the Java code independent from enums. At the cost of two gross switches in a single place.