# How can I map multiple enums into the same column in java spring?

Tags: java, database, jpa, enums

I have a field in a model object which takes an enum like this:

```
@Enumerated(...)
private UniveritySubject subject; //Of course not working like this...
```

For a better structure and a better overview I want to separate my subject in two enums: One enum representing winter and one enum representing summer subjects like this:

```
public class Subject {

    public enum Summer {
        ...
        MATH;
    }

    public enum Winter {
        ...
        PHYSICS;
    }
}
```

How can I achieve the mapping of either of those enums to the model column `subject`? Sadly it is not possible to inherite enums, so I can not have a "superclass enum". I thought about using one enum with boolean value `isInWinter`, but please regard that I have a lot of subjects and I think it isn't good to overview.
Is there any other solution?

Comment: This is a JPA (maybe Hibernate) question. It has almost nothing to do with Spring.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I removed the wrong tag.

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54093620/jpa-enum-inheritance

Comment: I took a look but honestly I don't have a clue why they are even using those enums the way they do...how would this correspond to my example?

Answer (score 1):

To normalize this a bit I would change the design. `UniversitySubject` should be an entity of its own, like (for example):

```
@Entity
public class UniversitySubject {
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Season season;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Subject subject;
}
```

where `Season` is:

```
enum Season { SPRING, SUMMER, AUTUMN, WINTER }
```

and `Subject`

```
enum Subject { MATH, PHYSICS, BIOLOGY }
```

and then in the class using it would be like

```
@ManyToOne
private UniversitySubject subject;
```

Also, to clarify things a bit maybe `UniversitySubject` could be named `TermSubject` or something alike?

Of course it is possible to use JPA annotations for example to concat all this stuff into one string and parse back but small changes in the design should make these 'hacks' unnecessary.

Comment: okay, kind of interesting...Now would there be a smarter way to model the seasons, if there are only two? Should I use a boolean instead?

Comment: @F_Schmidt You could have something like `boolean isWinter` but then if there appears other seasons later extending is a bit more complicated process.